# MATLAB: Segment Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, image-segmentation

New to MATLAB and image processing.I need to know how to segment an image into foreground and background, then generate a binary image as output.
[image]

I need this as an output:

[image]

I have already tried to accomplish this with online tutorials and this is what i managed to get:
[image]

Its a good start but not exactly what i need.

My Code:

```
I = imread('AssignmentInput.jpg');
figure;
imshow(I);
title('Step-1: Load input image');


img_filtered = I;
for c = 1 : 3
    img_filtered(:, :, c) = medfilt2(I(:, :, c), [3, 3]);
end
figure; 
imshow(img_filtered);
title('Step-3:Noise Removal');

H = fspecial('gaussian'); % Create the filter kernel.
img_filtered = imfilter(img_filtered,H); % Blur the image.
Mask = im2bw(img_filtered, 0.9); % Now we are generating the binary mask.
img_filtered([Mask, Mask, Mask]) = 0; % Now we have the image.
figure;
imshow(img_filtered);
title('Step-5:Segmented Image');
```

Comment: That looks pretty doggone close to me. What's the difference between the two images?

Comment: basically i keep the colour in the third image and i just need it as black and white as show in the second image.

Comment: That's only because you applied the mask to the original image. Try `imshow(~Mask)`

Comment: oh im such an idiot! i honestly did not see that. Thank you so much for pointing that out, i did not observe my code enough my fault.

Comment: Glad to help. It's easy to get caught up in what you think you need to do rather than look at what you've already got. :)

Comment: Also try out the colorThresholder app. It lets you play around with thresholding in a graphical user interface, and once you're done you can export your work as Matlab code.

Answer (score 0):

For a better noise removal process and cleaner separation between foreground and background, you can also add morphological operations like:

```
se = strel('square',2);
I = imclose(I,se);
```

You can try out different variations of 'strel' class also. The image below is after imclose operation with a square of 2 pixel [image]